Reading groups: Where to find them?
Hi if I want to find a reading group, for instance I want to read abbot's analysis, is there anywhere where I can find a group of people who have a reading group? Any forum etc?

It's somewhat easier at a university, but once you are outside it's really hard in my experience, so I would be interested in an answer as well.
